# Vuejs - Event not triggering when clicking button in component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

I have the next component, which is inside a modal tag. When clicking, the modal opens with the content fetched from said url.

```
<modal>
<laravel-view :url="'{{ '/post/view/' . $comment->source_id }}'"></laravel-view>
</modal>
```

It is defined here:

```
Vue.component('laravel-view',{
  template: '#laravel-view.vue-template',
  data(){
    return {
      viewHtml: null
    }
  },
  props: [
    'url'
  ],
  mounted() {
    this.loadPost(this.url)
  },
  methods: {
    loadPost(viewUrl){
      var self = this;
      $.get( viewUrl, function( htmlString ) {
        var compiled = Vue.compile('<div>' + htmlString + '</div>');
        self.viewHtml = htmlString;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And the template, from a blade file:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="laravel-view" class="vue-template">
    <div class="view-wrapper" v-html=viewHtml>
    </div>
</script>
```

When you click the laravel-view component, the modal opens (which is another component), and the content displayed would be the one it'd fetch from the link. This is the view returned from a controller with the information get from above:

```
<div>
    <div class="post" style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="{{ $post->image }}" style="margin: auto;" />
        <p>
            <h1 >{{ $post->title }}</h1>
            {{ $post->caption }}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comments">
        <div class="post-content">
        @foreach( $post->comments as $comment )
            <div class="comment activity-box-w" id="{{$comment->post_id}}">
                <div class="activity-box" style="align-items: normal">
                    <div style="margin-top: 5px">
                         <div class="activity-avatar" style="background-image: url({{ asset($comment->image) }}); float: left;">
                        </div>      
                    </div>

                  <div class="activity-info">
                    <div class="activity-role">
                      {{ '@' . $comment->username }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="ellipsis">
                        <div>
                            <p class="activity-title">{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="time">
                    {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($comment->created_at)->toDateTimeString() }}
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="post-pub" style="width: 100%;padding-top: 10px; margin-left: 25%;">
            <form style="width: 100%:">
                <textarea rows="1"></textarea>
                <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-s" v-on:click="commentPost">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've defined the method on both.js files (not that I need it on both; only to know where in the world it is triggered, assuming it does) and the event never triggers. I made sure the button worked by changing its type to "submit" and clicking it (which, reloaded the page). Still, the problem persists. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone interested, and hopefully this could be of use to someone experiencing the same problems, what happens is that:

As far as I could understand, the components were being re-rendered when they got the data from the source; yet, *it didn't include the script again*!, which, was the reason that the button wasn't responding at all. To solve this issue. I had to include it within the first blade file like this:

```
<laravel-view :url="'{{ '/post/view/' . $comment->source_id }}'"></laravel-view>
    <div class="post-pub" style="width: 100%;padding-top: 10px;">
        <form style="width: 100%:">
            <textarea rows="1" v-model="postComment" id="postCommentTextArea"></textarea>
            <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-s" @click="comment({{ $comment->id }})">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```